# LinqToExcel - Reading a decimal from an *.xlsx file

Tags: c#, excel, decimal, linq-to-excel

I've been fiddling around with this for a couple of hours now and i'm kind of walking in circles. I'm missing something.

I'm trying to read an excel sheet with Linq to Excel. Everything works in order, except for decimals in the sheet. I've tried a couple of different approaches, none of which seem to work.

The column I'm trying to read is a currency column. My model is decimal. When I leave the column in excel on the Currency format, I get 0's from the linq query.

When I set the colum to number, I get values with no decimal seperator.

The testfile I created has a sheet called DecimalSheet. The column is called DecimalTest and contains a number; 4587,61

I've got a testmodel like so;

```
public class DecimalModel
{
    [ExcelColumn("DecimalTest")]
    public decimal DecimalTest { get; set; }
}
```

Querying the file is implemented like this:

```
var testFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(fileLocation)
{
    DatabaseEngine = LinqToExcel.Domain.DatabaseEngine.Ace,
    TrimSpaces = LinqToExcel.Query.TrimSpacesType.Both,
    UsePersistentConnection = false, 
    ReadOnly = true
};

var decimalTestModel = from tb in testFile.Worksheet<DecimalModel>("DecimalSheet")
                       select tb;

var lines = decimalTestModel.ToList();
```

The readout is like this: 45876100000000000M

**EDIT 1**

In the meantime I've tried:

1. Reading the values as `string`. This presented me with the
   scientific notation of the value in the cell, no matter what kind of
   cell format i used. It reads "4,58761e+016" instead of 4587,61.
2. Setting the complete worksheet to text format and handling it as
   `string` as above. It reads "4,58761e+016" instead of "4587,61"
3. Reading the values as `Float. This made no difference.
4. I tried to work with culture settings as in setting the cultre to
   `nl-NL` hardcoded in the thread just before creating the factory and
   setting it back to the original culture after i'm done. This made no
   difference.

I noticed:

1. When the Excel document is kept open, the readouts with the above
   code are perfect. I don't want Excel kept open because of batch
   processing of Excel documents (on the server, no user interaction).
2. When I run the above testcode on a different server (Dutch Windows,
   Dutch Excel, Dutch Locale `nl-NL`) it works fine. It's on the
   English server 'en-US' locale that it doesn't work. Makes me think
   this has something todo with the localisation or culture?

Can anyone point me in the right direction how I can configure excel/change the code so that it reads the decimal correct?

Comment: What happens when you try with `float`? Also, have you missed a comma or dot in your readout?

Comment: I've tried with `Float`. But that didn't work eiter. output stays the same. Strange detail; when I leave excel open, it returns the correct value _4587,61_. That pointed me in the direction of a language issue. When I run this code on a production server (Dutch Excel + Windows version), it works fine! When I run this on my development server (English Windows + Excel) it doesnt work.

Comment: Kinda broad guess but what is the column type in excel? general, number, string? Could be a parsing issue with the comma for Dutch and English requires a dot.

Comment: Tried a couple of different settings, general, number, currency. Even tried text and manual parsing from string to decimal. solution was in my locale settings of the decelopment server (below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a couple of other options I also went to the github projectpage for this nuGet package and posted a question there as well (https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel/issues/143).

The solution was quite simple; change my locale in the windows date settings. Which makes sense for me since all the documents are in Dutch. Only windows is in English.

This is done via Control Panel -> Region

[image: Setting the format to Dutch]

[image: Setting the system locale to Dutch]